# Blank popup when using onload() function in javascript with Google Chrome Extension development

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Below is the code for popup.html page I am using the hello world example given at http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html

```
<html>
<head><title>Update Time</title>
<script>
function UpdateTime(){

    var today = new Date();
    var hour = today.getHours();
    var mins = today.getMinutes();
    var secs = today.getSeconds();

    if (secs <=9){
        secs = "0" + secs
    }

    var TotalTime = hour + ":" + mins + ":" + secs;

    if (document.layers) { 
        document.layers.time.document.write(TotalTime); 
        document.layers.time.document.close(); 
    }else if (document.all) { 
        time.innerHTML = TotalTime; 
    } 

    setTimeout("UpdateTime()", 1000) 

}
</script>


</head>

<body onload="UpdateTime()">

<span id=time style="position:absolute;"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

But all I am getting s a blank popup... what am I doing wrong? What needs to be done in order to show my javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if (document.layers) { 
    document.layers.time.document.write(TotalTime); 
    document.layers.time.document.close(); 
}else if (document.all) { 
    time.innerHTML = TotalTime; 
}
```

Do:

```
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = TotalTime;
```